# How do I get eth0 IP address

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, raspberrypi

When I type in this command line I got this.But it did not contain IP address.Actually I want to connect with Raspberry Pi with ssh connection.So do that I want to get IP address of eth0 .If there is a another method please let me know.

/sbin/ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:18:a4:2a:81  
      inet6 addr: fe80::223:18ff:fea4:2a81/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:30052 (30.0 KB)  TX bytes:5721 (5.7 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:d4600000-d4620000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:7349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:975794 (975.7 KB)  TX bytes:975794 (975.7 KB)

ppp0  Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:10.111.184.85  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:29662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:26318 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:28738852 (28.7 MB)  TX bytes:3274200 (3.2 MB)
```

Comment: What is this `inet6 addr: fe80::223:18ff:fea4:2a81/64` if not an IP address? Could it be you are not using ipv4 perhaps?

Comment: But ppp0 has ip address a inet addr:10.111.184.85 what is that ?

Comment: ppp - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol was/is(?) used for serial line and modem connections to the (inter-)net. Are you by any chance using some special hardware with your pi? Might be the ppp0 IP is what you look for, instead of eht0

Comment: That is probably it Hannu.

Answer (score 0):

first try

> /etc/init.d/networking restart

This will restart the networking service and eth0 will come up if your computer is connected to  a network.

Also check the /etc/network/interfaces files and see if there is eth0 interface in their. If not you can create config as below:

```
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.2.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.2
bridge_ports eth0
```

You can simply replace br0 with eth0 and get rid of the last line as well. For obvious you need to choose the ip address according to ip address class for your router. Reboot your system or restart the networking service as above.
Good Luck